# How to create a version of boost::range::transform that has an extra paramter for capturing context

Tags: c++, boost-range

For example I have a vector

```
std::vector<int> source;
```

and a struct

```
struct Foo {
 int x;
 int y;  
}
```

and I wish to do the following

```
Foo foo;
auto tr = source | boost::adaptors::transform([&](int i){return i+foo.x;};
```

However the above doesn't compile in the version of boost(1.55) and the compiler version(VS-2010) I am required to use. The problem is that when the lambda captures a variable by reference, the transform adaptor ends up trying to use the assign constructor which is illegal and fails to compile. However if nothing is captured then it all works.

My naive solution would be to wrap transform with another overload such that

```
Foo foo;
auto tr = source | boost::adaptors::transformed(foo, [](int i, Foo f){return i+f.x;};
```

This seems to be the pattern preferred by the std library. For example [std::lower_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) uses this pattern.

but as soon as I try to think about how to do that I get stuck in template madness trying to wrap the original transform function. If somebody could show me how to generate the overload I require I am sure I could extrapolate that to the other overloads I need.

The alternative solution is instead of using lambdas is to use full functors for each function but this is ugly if I can at least use non capturing lambdas.

Comment: can you modify the code so it's in the form of a complete compilation unit, along with correct includes? That way, it's easier for us to play with

Comment: `boost::adaptors::transform` is the non-`|` version. I think you mean `boost::adaptors::transformed`, which works fine with capturing lambdas

Comment: @caleth I meant transformed. Fixed now

Comment: @RichardHodges On Godbolt https://godbolt.org/g/cHm7g9 I can't pick the version of boost with the bug though on goldbolt. 1.55

Comment: @Caleth The problem is due to an old version of boost and an old version of visual studio. The error is a bug in boost 1.55

Comment: You just need to have a valid everything else: https://godbolt.org/g/H4SRfR

Comment: @Caleth I know that works. The problem is with an old boost and old compiler. I'm not asking for anybody to prove that linked code  compiles. I know it does under perfect conditions. I'm asking how to wrap transformed so that I use a different mechanism for capturing context.

Comment: Have you tried capturing a `std::reference_wrapper<Foo>` by value?

Comment: @Caleth the problem is I that as soon as the compiler generates a functor rather than a function pointer boost::transform fails. I am asking a specific question. How to wrap boost::adaptors::transformed. I'm not asking how to fix the bug.

Answer (score 1):

All the machinery of `boost::adaptors::transformed` funnels down to `boost::iterator::transform_iterator`. `transformed` is a type alias, so `transformed(fun)` is constructing an object, it isn't a function call to be overloaded.

The simplest thing would be to copy `iterator/transform_iterator.hpp` and `range/adaptor/transformed.hpp` into a `bitransform_iterator.hpp` and `bitransformed.hpp` with an extra `Param p` (and rename `UnaryFunctor` to `BinaryFunctor` for clarity)

Comment: Thanks for answering the question in the direction Im looking for +1. Any chance you would fill out the answer with more detail. I guess what dissapoints me about boost::range is the non trivial way to compose and build on existing infrastructure. I assumed naively that I could easily wrap **transformed** in a function but it seems, as you point out, you always have to start at zero and build again to implement extended features. Again thanks for the pointers.